# Deploying my Silverlight app

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, testing, setup-deployment

I have finished developing a Web application using Silverlight 5 (hosted in an ASP.Net project) with Visual Express 2013. I use SQL Server 2012 for my database, and I want to send my application to My Friend  in order to test it.

Can I create a DEMO and send him to test it, or should I send him the solution (`.SLN`) or what?
How can I show him my application without demanding him to compile the project?

Thanks you !

Comment: Perhaps you should talk to your teacher and see what they actually want. Anything you get from here is utterly pointless. e.g. we tell you "zip up everything and let the prof compile", and prof just wants the final .exe - boom, instant 0

Comment: He want just le .EXE , I think he dont want compile !

Comment: This is entirely dependent on your professor, asking us what your professor wants is pointless. Probably a good idea to remove the question to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give him access to the server which serves up the web page which hosts the Silverlight application.

Why?

If the app is accessing a database, how is your friend going to be able to have the app access the database to get the proper data?

Hence you need to publish your Silverlight application to a location which 1) has access to the database and 2) allows for your friend to bring up the web page which hosts the Silverlight app.

Otherwise if you give him the solution, he will also need to create a database and you need to give him a backup of the database as well and make sure the access parameters to *his* database server are the same.

Comment: So , I can't generate a demo for my application that contain the data base ?

Comment: @user160545 only if your database is a local database published with the app.